# Unexpected behavior on ELB with Route 53

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-route53, amazon-elb

I set up 2 EC2 instances where I hosted 2 different apps. One of them is a React app running on nginx and the other one is a Wordpress app.

I wanted to have them both hosted under the same domain like this:

www.example.com -> React app

www.example.com/blog -> Wordpress app

I managed to get this working properly using an ELB on HTTP.
The problem came when I added a SSL certificate for my domain and configured it to work with HTTPS.

This is the current configuration for HTTP, I'm redirecting all the traffic from it to HTTPS like this:

[image: HTTP CONFIGURATION]

The configuration for HTTPS is the following:

[image: HTTPS CONFIGURATION]

Current behavior:
When going to www.example.com it correctly forwards me to my React app.
When going to www.example.com/blog it also forwards me to my react app instead of redirecting me to the wordpress app.
But when refreshing and deleting cache (cmd + shift + R), it correctly forwards me to the wordpress app.

Whats weird to me is that this configuration works for HTTP and not for HTTPS.

Any thoughts on what could be happening?

**EDIT:**

Opening `www.example.com/blog` from an incognito window, correctly redirects me to my wordpress app. 
But once I navigate into `www.example.com`, I am not able to navigate to my wordpress app anymore

Making a request from CURL to `www.example.com/blog` I correctly receive my wordpress app response.

**EDIT 2:**

I'm using ROUTE 53 in order to redirect all my traffic to www.example.com to my ELB. I managed to do this by adding an A record.

**EDIT 3:**
If I use the ELB DNS name, it correctly forwards me to my wordpress app. 
It seems that Route 53 is causing this problem.

Comment: Review the ALB logs to determine whether the balancer is actually doing this... or not.  Try incognito mode. Test with `curl`. The different behavior on refresh suggests some interaction with the browser cache.  There are a lot of possibilities but we definitely need more detail, since there's nothing obviously wrong with the ALB config.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. What info should I check in the logs?